# Continuous differentiability of $A(\cdot)v$ implies $A(t) \in \mathcal{L}(Y,X)$.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $X,Y$ be Banach spaces, $\{A(t)\}_{t\geq 0}$ - a family of generators of $C_0$-semigroups on $X$ such that an $X$-valued function: $t \to A(t)v$ is continuously differentiable for all $v \in Y$, where $Y = D(A(t)) = D$ equipped with the norm $\| v \|_{Y} := \| v \|_{X} + \|A(0)v\|_{X}$. We know that $Y$ is continuously imbedded in $X$. Trivially, $A(0) \in \mathcal{L}(Y,X)$. Is it true that for all $t > 0$, $A(t) \in \mathcal{L}(Y,X)$? For each $v \in Y$, we have that $\|A(t)v\| \leq 1 + L_{t,v} \cdot t$, where $L_{t,v} = \max_{s \in [0,t]}{\|A'(s)v\|} < \infty$. This follows from the mean value theorem and the boundedness of the derivative on compact interval. What if we take the supremum of $\|A(t)v\|$ over all $\|v\|_{Y} = 1$. Can we get some upper bound for $L_{t,v}$ not depending on $v$?

Comment: Have you tried using the uniform boundedness principle?
In your notation you have $\sup_{s\in(0,t]}\left\lVert \frac{A(s)-A(0)}{s}v \right\rVert\leq L_{t,v}$. Thus the UBP should tell you that $\sup_{s\in(0,t]}\left\lVert \frac{A(s)-A(0)}{s} \right\rVert\leq C_t$ for some constant $C_t>0$ depending on $t$.

Comment: Don't we have to assume, in order to use UBP that for each $s \in (0,t]$ the operator $\frac{A(s) - A(0)}{s}$ is bounded?

Comment: Since $A(t)$ is the generator of a $C_0$-semigroup, it is closed. So by the closed graph theorem $A(t)\in\mathcal{L}(Y,X)$. Hence $\frac{A(s)-A(0)}{s}$ is bounded. Although now I realize that you might not need the UBP anyway since boundedness follows from the closed graph theorem.. ;-)

Comment: It works, $A(t)$ is closed as an operator on $X$, but I checked that it is also closed as an operator from $Y$ to $X$. The norm on $Y$ is using the operator $A(0)$, but it can be equivalently changed to $A(t)$, this gives closedness of $A(t) : Y \to X$. Anyway, your idea helped me to prove that $t \to A(t)$ is continuous in the operator norm, thanks.